# If $A^TA=I$ does it imply that $AA^T=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A:U\to V$ be a bounded linear operator.
Suppose that $A^TA=I_U$. Does this mean that $A^TA=I_V$?
If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Are $U$ and $V$ potentially infinite-dim?

Comment: Hint: if $U$ and $V$ have different dimensions, what could the rank of $A$ possibly be?

Comment: What if we require that $\dim(U)=\dim(V)$?

Comment: The question in the title is right, right?  But in the body there is a typo.

Comment: Anyway, if they are of finite and equal dimension, it is definitely true (assuming $AA^T=I$ is the correct conclusion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is NO. To see that, check the following matrix: $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider left-multiplication by  $A = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0}$ as a linear operator from $\Bbb R^1$ to $\Bbb R^3$.